# Check if one date and time is between a date and time range

Tags: javascript

Here I am trying to register for an event on 
15-April-2018 from 6 PM to 7 PM.

But some user has blocked the place 
from 10-April-2018 to 18-April-2018 from 4 PM to 5 PM.

The user has blocked from 4 PM to 5 PM, **not from 6 PM to 7 PM**.

I need to find whether given date and time fall between blocked date and time using pure JavaScript.

This is what I tried so far. It is not allowing to register it.

```
var blockedstartTime = new Date("2018","04","10","16","00","00").getTime();
var blockedendTime = new Date("2018","04","18","17","00","00").getTime();

var eventstartTime = new Date("2018","04","15","18","00","00").getTime();
var eventendTime = new Date("2018","04","15","19","00","00").getTime();

if(Math.min(blockedstartTime, blockedendTime) < Math.max(eventstartTime, 
eventendTime) && Math.max(blockedstartTime, blockedendTime) > 
Math.min(eventstartTime, eventendTime)) {
   console.log("Not Allow");
} else {
   console.log("Allow");
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `doesOverlap()` `function` in the following code block detects whether either the `start` and/or `end` of `param` `A` overlaps the `start` and/or `end` of `param` `B`.

The `isAvailable()` `function` `returns` `false` if `doesOverlap()` ever `returns` `true`.

See [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for more info.

```js
// Blocked times.
var blockedTimes = Array.from(new Array(9)).map(function(x, i) {
  return {
    start: new Date("2018","04",(10+i).toString(),"16","00","00"),
    end: new Date("2018","04",(10+i).toString(),"17","00","00")
  }
})

// Events.
var threeToFive = {
  start: new Date("2018","04","15","15","00","00"),
  end: new Date("2018","04","15","17","00","00")
}
var sixToSeven = {
  start: new Date("2018","04","15","18","00","00"),
  end: new Date("2018","04","15","19","00","00")
}

// Does overlap.
function doesOverlap(A, B) {
  if (A.start > B.start && A.end < B.end) {
    return 'A between B'
  } else if (A.start < B.start && A.end > B.end) {
    return 'A over B'
  } else if (A.start < B.start && A.end > B.start) {
    return 'A over B.start'
  } else if (A.start < B.end && A.end > B.end) {
    return 'A over B.end'
  }
  return false // No overlap.
}

// Is available.
function isAvailable(event, blockedTimes) {
  return !blockedTimes.some(function(time) {
    return doesOverlap(event, time)
  })
}

// Proof.
console.log('Apr 15 3-5pm time slot is available:', isAvailable(threeToFive, blockedTimes))
console.log('Apr 15 6-7pm time slot is available:', isAvailable(sixToSeven, blockedTimes))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Sencha ExtJS. I think it doesn't support ES6. Getting Rhino Parse Error ( Syntax Error => ).

Comment: See above for `ES5` @Goutam.A.S

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the first user blocks only an hour from first date to last date - that is, between 16:00 to 17:00 each day.

Now when you want to allocate time, you need to get a list of all the reserved times. There is no simple range between two different dates in your case.

```
var blocks = []; 

blocks.push({
   start: new Date("2018","04","10","16","00","00").getTime(),
   end: new Date("2018","04","10","17","00","00").getTime(); 
});

blocks.push({
   start: new Date("2018","04","11","16","00","00").getTime(),
   end: new Date("2018","04","11","17","00","00").getTime(); 
});
```

You will have to do the above operation using a loop I guess.

Now here is how you can test a given range overlaps any blocked time.

```
   var eventstartTime = new Date("2018","04","15","18","00","00").getTime();
   var eventendTime = new Date("2018","04","15","19","00","00").getTime();

   blocks.forEach(function(aBlock){
       if ((eventstartTime > aBlock.start && eventstartTime < aBlock.end) || 
           (eventendTime > aBlock.start && eventendTime < aBlock.end)) 
          console.log('Not allowed')  
   })
```

It simply checks if your event time falls crosses any blocked time.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation.